# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: | Discord.py

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, discord.py

When trying to make a change prefix command when I get this error when trying to change the current prefix:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: e

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\achut\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\achut\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\achut\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: OperationalError: no such column: e
```

The code for the command is this:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
async def change_prefix(ctx, newprefix: str):
    if len(newprefix) > 5:
        await ctx.send("The server prefix cannot be less than 5 characters in length!")

    else:
        cursor.execute(f"UPDATE guilds SET prefix = {newprefix} WHERE serverid = {ctx.guild.id}")
        connection.commit()
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(title = f"Prefix Changed to `{newprefix}`",description = f"The bot's server prefix was just changed to `{newprefix}`!", colour=0x04ff00))
```

Sorry if this could be an easy fix but I'm really bad at sqlite3. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming `prefix` is a VARCHAR column in the database, the value you're setting must be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: I tried it with the single quotes on discord and it worked but is there any way to allow the user to enter a prefix without single quotes?

Comment: If you use placeholder values in the SQL statement, then it puts in the quotes for you automatically.  `cursor.execute("UPDATE guilds SET prefix = %s WHERE serverid = %s", [newprefix, ctx.guild.id])`

Comment: Can you please show me an example of how to put the placeholder values in the SQL statement?

Comment: I get this error: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

Comment: Hmm.  Some databases use `%s` as the placeholder token and others use `?`, and I can never remember which is which.  Try using `?` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need single quotes around `{newprefix}` in the SQL command. With this the user won't need to add the quotes on Discord.

```
cursor.execute(f"UPDATE guilds SET prefix = '{newprefix}' WHERE serverid = {ctx.guild.id}")
```